# RxJS - Queueing ajax requests from separate inputs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a list of multiple inputs (dynamically generated - unknown number).

- I want each to trigger an ajax request on every keystroke
- I want these ajax requests to be queued up, so only one is sent to
  the server at a time, and the next one is sent only after getting a response from the earlier one.
- if new requests are triggered from an input that already has requests in the queue, I want the old ones associated with the same input to be cancelled.
- if new requests are triggered from an input that does *not* already have inputs in the queue, I want the new requests to just be added to the end of the queue without cancelling anything.

I'm told that RxJS makes these kinds of complicated async operations easy, but I can't seem to wrap my head around all the RxJS operators.

I have queueing working with a single input below, but I don't really understand why the defer is necessary or how to queue requests for separate inputs while maintaining the switchMap-like behavior I think I want for individual inputs themselves.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
    $("#input"),
    'keyup'
)
.map((event) => {
    return $("#input").val();
});
.concatMap((inputVal) => {
    return Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
        fetch(myURL + inputVal)
    ))
    .catch(() => Rx.Observable.empty());
})
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create some sort of function that manages each input. Something along the following lines

```
requestAtKeyStroke(inputId: string) {
   return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
           $(inputId),
           'keyup'
         )
         .map((event) => {
            return $("#input").val();
         })
        .filter(value => value.length > 0)
        .switchMap((inputVal) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(myURL + inputVal)))
}
```

Such a function deals with your third requisite, to cancel requests still on fly when a new one arrives. The key here is the `switchMap` operator.

Then what you can do is to merge all the Observables corresponding to your inputs into one Observable. One way could be the following

```
Observable.from(['input1, 'input2']).map(input => requestAtKeyStroke(input)).mergeAll()
```

This is not fulfilling all you requisites, since you still may have more than one requests under execution at the same time, coming from different inputs. I am not sure though if it is possible to fulfill all your requisites at the same time.